# How to Generate Placeholders in Stylus

Tags: css, code-generation, stylus

I'm looking to generate placeholders and variables that can change depending on configured **proportions** such as the following:

- `$small-margin-top`
- `$large-margin-top`
- `$small-padding-bottom`

Where each placeholder applies the corresponding, generated variable to the rule:

```
$small-margin-top
    margin-top $marginsmall

$large-margin-top
    margin-top $marginLarge

$small-padding-bottom
    margin-bottom $marginSmall
```

I have statically defined the variables for now:

```
/* Margin */
$margin = 1rem
$marginsmall = $margin / $multiplier
$marginlarge = $margin * $multiplierLarge
$marginmini = $marginSmall / $multiplierLarge
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: expected "name" to be a string, but got ident:marginmini

```
properties = margin padding

proportions = mini small medium large

directions = top left bottom right

for property in properties
    for proportion in proportions
            for direction in directions
                ${property}-{direction}-{proportion}
                    {property}-{direction} lookup(property + proportion)
```

How can I generate placeholders for my `proportions` variable, such that the generated placeholders may be extended later (`@extend $margin-large`)?

---

**EDIT: [here is the working solution](https://gist.github.com/srsgores/f1b9e63d957f84c2843f)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lookup` bif accepts a string, and you are passing an ident (margin, padding, etc. without quotes). You can convert them to string by using concatenation. Also, you miss a `$` sign:

```
properties = margin padding

proportions = mini small medium large

directions = top left bottom right

for property in properties
    for proportion in proportions
        for direction in directions
            ${proportion}-{property}-{direction}
                {property}-{direction} lookup('$' + property + proportion)
```

Comment: Stylus won't compile the ``${proportion}``; PHPStorm is saying it's a "Unexpected Element - BAD character".  And if I escape it with ``\``, the placeholders are still not generated (failed to extend) if I define ``$marginmini = 0.4rem`` and ``@extend $margin-mini-top``... ideas?

Comment: It is completely valid syntax. I think that PHPStorm just doesn't know anything about placeholder selectors, because they are relatively new, and PHPStorm doesn't update Stylus support. From your question, you should write `@extend $mini-margin-top`, or change variables order in the loop. You can test this code online on http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html or Codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FCGew).

Comment: Indeed, I had to "trigger watcher regardless of syntax errors" in the watcher config.  Also, how about setting variables?  I tried ``${proportion}{property}{direction} = (i * $multiplier * $em)`` before the generated placeholders, but no luck: http://codepen.io/srsgores/pen/FJqhg

Comment: > Also, how about setting variables?
For this we have the `define` bif. See http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#definename-expr

Comment: Seems like it should work, but it's not generating units for me: http://codepen.io/srsgores/pen/xyGlu - ``define("" + proportion + property + direction, unit(i / 3, "em"))``... ideas?

Comment: You're using it wrong again :) First of all, where is `$` in define? And secondly, you're defining variable `proportion + property + direction`, but trying to lookup `property + proportion`.

Comment: Perfect.  Here's the final snippet: https://gist.github.com/srsgores/f1b9e63d957f84c2843f