# Stylus: Generate CamelCase Variable

Tags: javascript, css, stylus

Looking to generate camelCase placeholders in a newly-generated Stylus variable (follow-up question [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375087/how-to-generate-placeholders-in-stylus)):

- `smallMarginTop`
- `normalMarginTop`

etc.

```
properties = margin padding

proportions = mini small normal medium large

for property in properties
    for proportion, i in proportions // Generate basic proportion placeholders: ex. small-padding, medium-padding, etc.
        define("$" + property + proportion, unit(i / 3, "em")) // should give something like $marginSmall = ... -- thinking something like toUpperCase?
```

How can this be achieved, either with the Javascript API or natively, within Stylus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `to-upper-case` function in Stylus, but you can easily add it using JS API and [use](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#usepath) built-in function. For example:

**to-upper-case.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
  return function(stylus) {
    stylus.define('to-upper-case', function(node) {
      var nodeName = node.nodeName
        , val = node.string;

      if ('string' == nodeName) {
        return new stylus.nodes.String(val.toUpperCase());
      } else if ('ident' == nodeName) {
        return new stylus.nodes.Ident(val.toUpperCase());
      } else {
        throw new Error('to-upper-case accepts string or ident but got "' + nodeName + '"');
      }
    });
  };
};
```

**test.styl**

```
use('to-upper-case.js')

properties = margin padding

proportions = mini small normal medium large

for property in properties
  for proportion, i in proportions
    define("$" + property + to-upper-case('' + substr(proportion, 0, 1)) + substr(proportion, 1), unit(i / 3, "em"))
```

Comment: Not working for me.  Stylus just gives out variables when they're not defined.  Using the exact same code you provided, the most success I've had is ``$marginMini``, but still, that's always 0.  Can you provide a working example?  Maybe a codepen?

Comment: Here's a gist, where I'm getting a different problem: https://gist.github.com/srsgores/2ade408a99af1f41d252  I get the error message "to-upper-case accepts string or ident but got function", while trying to wrap the function in a native stylus one:

Comment: You get this error, because Stylus have built-in functions with only one letter (e.g. `s` and `p`). You should convert them to string using concatenation:
`to-upper-case('' + substr(string, 0, 1)) + substr(string, 1)`. Or you can modify plugin code to accept functions (return function.name.toUpperCase())

Comment: It worked.  Anyone interested in a working example of this should see my new helpers.styl: https://github.com/srsgores/stylus-boilerplate/blob/master/app/styles/stylus/helpers/helpers.styl